# react ios build error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to run react native. But when I tried to build ios the below errors are showing

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following commands produced analyzer issues:
>
> Analyze Base/RCTPlatform.m  Analyze Views/RCTTabBarItem.m
>
> Analyze Views/RCTTabBar.m   Analyze Profiler/RCTProfile.m (4 commands
>   with analyzer issues)
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileC
>   /apps/snp/snapstaff_talent/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTPlatform.o
>   Base/RCTPlatform.m normal x86_64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler   CompileC
>   /apps/snp/snapstaff_talent/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTabBarItem.o
>   Views/RCTTabBarItem.m normal x86_64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler   CompileC
>   /apps/snp/snapstaff_talent/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTabBar.o
>   Views/RCTTabBar.m normal x86_64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler   CompileC
>   /apps/snp/snapstaff_talent/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTProfile.o
>   Profiler/RCTProfile.m normal x86_64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler   Analyze
>   Base/RCTPlatform.m    Analyze Views/RCTTabBarItem.m   Analyze
>   Views/RCTTabBar.m     Analyze Profiler/RCTProfile.m   Libtool
>   /apps/snp/snapstaff_talent/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a
>   normal x86_64     Ld
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snapstaff_talent.app/snapstaff_talent
>   normal x86_64     GenerateDSYMFile
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snapstaff_talent.app.dSYM
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snapstaff_talent.app/snapstaff_talent
>     Ld
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snapstaff_talentTests.xctest/snapstaff_talentTests
>   normal x86_64     GenerateDSYMFile
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snapstaff_talentTests.xctest.dSYM
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snapstaff_talentTests.xctest/snapstaff_talentTests
>   (13 failures)
>
> Installing
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/snapstaff_talent.app An
>   error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=LaunchServicesError, code=0): The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.) Launching
>   org.reactjs.native.example.snapstaff-talent An error was encountered
>   processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
>   The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain
>   error 4.)

I am new on react native. I am using OS X El Capitan. please help me out of this.

Comment: hey did you find a  solution yet i'm having a similar problem .. thanks

Comment: @user3521011 Sorry buddy just recreated the app and it's solved.